# Is it possible to NOT add data into a database when a certain condition is met? Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to NOT add data to the database if a certain condition is met.
Is it possible, and if so, what's the syntax?

```
import sqlite3

text = input('> ')

def DO_NOT_ADD_DATA():
    con = sqlite3.connect('my db file.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    
    if "a" in text():
        print("Uh Oh")
        # I want to NOT add data in this part, it still gets added but it does print out Uh Oh 

    else:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('value1', 'value2')")

    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: An `if` statement works fine. However, I'm pretty sure your example is not a minimal reproducible example for your problem, since it has a syntax error in the `INSERT` statement. (Look at the quotes.) Please show us a minimal reproducible example that exhibits your issue.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I apologize for the incorrect syntax.. I've already edited my code.

Comment: Your code still doesn't work - you can't call `text`, a string. After you fix that, you still don't have the table that insert statement would affect. If you did, then you'd find your code works fine and the query won't be executed if there's an `a` in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is quite possible. And you have multiple ways of doing it.

You could do it as in your example (if you fix the syntax errors), where the python script can perform some complex evaluation of whether to perform the operation.

If you instead want to avoid inserting duplicates, you would probably not check so in python, as you can run into race conditions (e.g. if you were to query the database first whether entry 'a' already exists, it doesn't, but another process sneaks in the entry in the time between you've checked and actually inserted it).

In these cases you can actually build your database to ensure it always upholds some constraints. In these cases, you could put a "UNIQUE" constaint on the column, and if you attempted to insert a duplicate, the database will throw you an error, so you can react accordingly.

See e.g. https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html, https://sqlite.org/syntax/column-constraint.html, https://sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html.

Whether you want to do one or another really, really depends on what you actually want to acheive.

(Note: The race conditions could be prevented by using transactions, and sometimes transactions and locking rows/tables/databases is preferred over using constraints in the database schema. It all really depends.)

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful but since the UNIQUE constraint only works for duplicate values, it doesn't kind of answer my question. I just wanted to cancel the data transaction if that condition was met but I'll still be able to implement this onto my program, thanks again.

Comment: The UNIQUE constraint was just an example. You could also add a constraint that checks whether "a" is in the inserted value. Please also see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108162/python-sqlite3-insert-into-table-valuedictionary-goes-here/16698310#16698310 for examples of placeholders, as they safeguard against sql injection.